# Hibernate JDBC connection closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

I've a problem with my connection. I used [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) 3 and [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) 4 (Oracle Connection) in my [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) layer. I open a session and close it in every method I have. After some time the application server ([Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)), I think the Tomcat server reset the connection, so when I open my application, do process and try to open the connection, I get this message:

> HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Closed Connection

Comment: We need the full stacktrace of this problem.

Comment: How about using Spring's transaction support?